Running OpenMP threads on isolated CPUs
How can the CPU affinity for OpenMP threads be set on a (Linux) system with cores removed from the scheduler (e.g. using the isolcpus boot parameter)?
On a system where only the first 12 cores are available to the scheduler (isolcpus=12-127), calling the OpenMP program with
GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=64-127 OMP_NUM_THREADS=64 taskset --cpu-list 64-127 command

all 64 OpenMP threads run on CPU 64.
With
GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=64-127 OMP_NUM_THREADS=64 command

All 64 OpenMP threads run on CPUs 0-12.
How can I get the 64 OpenMP threads to run on CPUs 64-127?
I could do it programmatically within the software using
#pragma omp parallel for
for(...)
  pthread_setaffinity_np(...)

Is there any way this can be done externally when starting the OpenMP program?
(Note: A similar issue was brought up in Core isolation limits OpenMP to a single core but no solution was provided. The given answer "I think you are asking OpenMP to do something that is impossible." is not true, as all that the OpenMP library needs to do is to call pthread_setaffinity_np() or equivalent functions. It shouldn't even need taskset to run on a CPU specified in GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY.)

GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY is not standard because it only works with one specific implementation. You should not use that. OMP_PLACES and OMP_PROC_BIND are the standard variable. OpenMP places let you place thread to core, possibly each thread on a specific core or multiple one. Thus using taskset is not needed. IDK about isolcpus.

It looks like this question is the same than the previous one (so a duplicate), not just similar. If you think the answer is not true, you can add a comment to the previous answer, open a bounty so to attract new people answering it, but not open a new (same) question. Even assuming the previous answer is wrong and this question is answered properly, this will introduce confusion for future readers (some may just read the other question/answer).

Also note that calling pthread_setaffinity_np in a parallel for is not a good idea. Besides being not portable, iterations are scheduled to OpenMP threads so this conflits with the OpenMP scheduler. You should at least do this in omp parallel sections, and not for construct which are work-sharing ones. In fact, I think it is not a good idea to use that at all (see the comment about standard OpenMP variables for thread binding).

CPU isolation is the key in this issue. Anybody here who runs OpenMP software on isolated cores? How do you do it?

It appears that both Intel libiomp and GNU libgomp must be intersecting the affinity mask inherited from the calling process (non-isolated cores 0-11) with any GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY, KMP_AFFINITY or OMP_PLACES specifiers. Hence taskset is needed.
Here is what works for Intel:
KMP_AFFINITY=explicit,proclist=[12-191] taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command
OMP_PLACES="12:180" taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command
OMP_PLACES="{12}:180" taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command

This works for GNU:
GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=12-191 taskset --cpu-list 12-191 taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command # note the double taskset
OMP_PLACES="{12},{13},(explicitly list all cores),{191}" taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command
OMP_PLACES="{12}:180" taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command

This does not work for Intel:
taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command
KMP_AFFINITY=explicit,proclist=[12-191] command
OMP_PLACES="12:180" command
OMP_PROC_BIND=true OMP_PLACES="12:180" command

This does not work for GNU:
taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command
OMP_PLACES="12:180" taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command
OMP_PLACES="12:180" taskset --cpu-list 12-191 taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command
GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=12-191 taskset --cpu-list 12-191 command
OMP_PLACES="{12},{13},(explicitly list all cores),{191}" command

OMP_NUM_THREADS=180 and isolcpus=12-191 in all examples.

"It appears that both Intel libiomp and GNU libgomp must be intersecting the affinity mask inherited from the calling process": It is good behaviour to respect the incoming affinity, since that is often set by the higher level systems being used to run parallel jobs, especially in an MPI environment. Since OpenMP can't see what has been asked at that level (other than by respecting what it has done), it is entirely sane for OpenMP runtimes to use only the cores which are allowed in the affinity mask.

I disagree that it is good behavior, I and consider it bad, unexpected behavior.
GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY, KMP_AFFINITY and OMP_PLACES are mechanisms to instruct OpenMP runtimes what to do, namely to call pthread_setaffinity_np() accordingly. It is surprising that these mechanism do not have the effect their names and documentation suggest and promise. Is there any documentation that says the runtime intersects the user specified affinities with process masks?

First, note this (from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html ) "The system may further restrict the set of CPUs on which the thread runs if the "cpuset" mechanism described in cpuset(7) is being used.  These restrictions on the actual set of CPUs on which the thread will run are silently imposed by the kernel.", so it may well be that this is not an OpenMP runtime choice at all! Second, if you want to frighten yourself, look at the relevant code in the LLVM (~= Intel) runtime  (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_affinity.cpp).

OMP_PLACES etc are mechanisms to instruct OpenMP to (try to) use certain cores. If that request is unsuccessful for whatever reason (including invalid or restricted values), that's a different story (->error handling). cpuset restrictions are irrelevant here. cpuset is not the same as ìsolcpus. ìsolcpus` is not a restriction for processes. It's a hint to the scheduler.

Additionally, sched_setaffinity(2) fails with EINVAL if "The affinity bit mask mask contains no processors that are (...) permitted to the thread according to any restrictions that may be imposed by (...) the "cpuset" mechanism (...)" There is no need for OMP to try to fix invalid user affinity requests behind the back of the user. Intersecting process masks is bad practice, in my opinion. OMP should throw an error if the user request is invalid. This is what  sched_setaffinity does. OMP_PLACES and *_AFFINITY should just be an interface to this like their names and documentation suggests.
